# Inverse of a Query

Tags: mysql

What would be the inverse of the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_result` 
INNER JOIN `perinfo` ON `test_result`.`mobileno` = `perinfo`.`mobileno` 
WHERE `perinfo`.`insti_id` = '2' 
  AND `test_id` = (SELECT `test_id` 
                   FROM `test` 
                   WHERE `test_name` = 'One')
```

i want to select rows from database table 'perinfo' where insti_id is 2 and also they are present in data table 'test_result'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_result` `t`
INNER JOIN `perinfo` ON `test_result`.`mobileno` = `perinfo`.`mobileno` 
WHERE `perinfo`.`insti_id` = '2' 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `test` 
                 WHERE `test_name` = 'One'
                   AND `test_id` = `t`.`test_id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your filter uisng `!=` (not equal) condition  instead of `=` (equal)

```
  SELECT * FROM `test_result` 
  INNER JOIN `perinfo` ON `test_result`.`mobileno` = `perinfo`.`mobileno` 
  WHERE `perinfo`.`insti_id` != '2' 
    AND `test_id` != (SELECT `test_id` 
                     FROM `test` 
                     WHERE `test_name` = 'One')
```

but if you have more then a result from subquery you should is IN or NOT IN

```
  SELECT * FROM `test_result` 
  INNER JOIN `perinfo` ON `test_result`.`mobileno` = `perinfo`.`mobileno` 
  WHERE `perinfo`.`insti_id` != '2' 
    AND `test_id` NOT IN  (SELECT `test_id` 
                     FROM `test` 
                     WHERE `test_name` = 'One')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "the inverse of a query", but to obtain the results you describe in the question's text you'd want to use

```
SELECT *
  FROM `perinfo`
  INNER JOIN `test_result` 
    ON `test_result`.`mobileno` = `perinfo`.`mobileno` 
  WHERE `perinfo`.`insti_id` = '2'
```

In other words, just reverse the positions of `perinfo` and `test_result` in the query, and remove the sub-select on `test` because it's not specified as part of the desired results.